# Count number of bullets in Active word Documents VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using this code to count number of bullets in word documents. But its always returning zero.

```
Sub FindBullet()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

'Select Entire document
Selection.WholeStory

With Selection
    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
        If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then

            count = count + 1

        End If
    Next
End With

'Gives the count of bullets in a document
MsgBox count

End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure you have exactly `wdListBullet type`? check with other styles according to [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840653%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or add some `or` options to your `if statement`.

Comment: @KazJaw Ya You were right, I was using wrong WdListType. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just opened up a blank Word doc, popped the code in and ran it, and it is returning however many bullets I put in. I did not modify your code...

Could your bullets really be something else, like a numbered list or some other symbol?